# Pythagorean Theorem Program in C

Tags: c, geometry

```
#include <stdio.h>

float function (float x, float y);
float function2 (float x, float z);
float function3 (float y, float z);

float main()

{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z; 

    {

    printf("Please insert length of adjacent side");
    scanf("%f", &x); 

    printf("Please insert length of opposite side");
    scanf("%f", &y); 

    printf("Please insert length of the hypotenuse");
    scanf("%f", &z);


    }

    {

    if (z = 0){
        printf("The length of the hypotenuse is %f",  function (x, y));}

    else if (y = 0){ 
        printf("The length of the opposite side is %f",  function2(x, z));} 

    else if (x=0){
        printf("The length of the adjacent side is %f",  function3(y, z));} 

    }

}


float function(float x, float y) {

    return(sqrt(((x*x)+(y*y))));

}

float function2(float x, float z) {

    return(sqrt(((z*z)-(x*x))));

}

float function3(float y, float z){

    return(sqrt(((z*z)-(y*y))));

}
```

This is the code that I have to figure out the missing side of a right triangle. The input for the side that you do not know is 0. When I run the program it asks me for all the sides but then it does not go on and give me the answer...Could anyone please explain this?
Thanks

Comment: Someone is going to suggest Yoda conditionals in 3, 2, 1...

Comment: You should also check the case where one (or more) of the variables are negative.

Comment: A few hints. Function 2 and 3 are performing the exact same operation, you might want to consider reusing one of the functions. The variable names x y z are really bad, considering they mean "adjacent", "opposite" and "hypotenuse" in your program. Use those names instead- it will be easier to understand and debug. Same for the functions- naming a function "function" is pointless- the name should describe what it does. Finally, not really related to programming, "adjacent" and "opposite" imply they are relative to a particular point on the triangle, which is never specified, so is irrelevant.

Comment: yea thanks for that, i did change the opp and adj. I guess ive got to much pre calc stuck in my head :D

Answer (score 8):

`=` is an assignment operator. Replace `z = 0` and any others like it with `z == 0`

```
if (z == 0){ // = changed to ==
    printf("The length of the hypotenuse is %f",  function (x, y));}

else if (y == 0){ // = changed to ==
    printf("The length of the opposite side is %f",  function2(x, z));} 

else if (x == 0){ // = changed to ==
    printf("The length of the adjacent side is %f",  function3(y, z));}
```

[C Operators Reference Sheet](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/1.5.html)

Comment: Hey @Marcus, you should select this as the answer to your problem. Or admin should.